# Pass parameters into ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to pass parameters into nested ui-view:

```
<ui-view user="user"></ui-view>
```

And now let me explain why do I need this.
That is how my ui looks like:

[image]

It's user card Angular component. Inside this component there are several tabs like subcomponents with own states. My goal is to **provide user object for the tabs** from the parent state.

Let me also show some simplified code:

```
  .state('user', {
    url: '/user/:userId',
    template: `<user user-id="userId"></user>`,
    controller: ($scope, $stateParams) => {
      $scope.userId = +$stateParams.userId;
    }
  })
  ...
  .state('user.tab1', {
    url: '/tab1',
    template: '<tab1 user="$ctrl.user"></tab1>',
    controller: ($scope, $state) => {
      //I would like to get access to the user object here
      let course = $scope.$ctrl.user;
    }
  });
```

So one more time: user object is loaded not in ui-router controller, but controller of component. Template of this component has nested  in which I would like to have user object.

Comment: Ui-router was not updated to follow angular 1.5 components. So yep, this is missing. You can pass object using $scope (not $scope.$ctrl) or similar workarounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that **ui-router does not create isolated scope for child states**,
so you can easily access them by

```
$scope.$ctrl.youparentproperty
```

and in my case it's:

```
.state('user.tab1', {
  url: '/tab1',
  template: '<tab1 user="$ctrl.user"></tab1>',
});
```

and the plunker with example, if somebody else struggling with the same issue - https://plnkr.co/edit/9LSNtWWcom6ERZRBucXB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the parent of a state via the parent property.

```
.state('user', {
        url: '/user/:userId',
        template: `<user user-id="userId"></user>`,
        controller: ($scope, $stateParams) => {
          $scope.userId = +$stateParams.userId;
        }
      })
      ...
      .state('user.tab1', {
        url: '/tab1',
        parent: 'user',
        template: '<tab1 user="$ctrl.user"></tab1>',
        controller: ($scope, $state) => {
          //In order to access the scope of a parent controller in Angular UI Router use:
          let course = $scope.$parent.user;
        }
      });
```

Another solution can be to put your User variables into a service you can access in every controller or to put in the `$rootscope`.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but I think `$scope.$parent` and `$rootScope` are not the best practices